# How to render React Component from Kendo SiteFinity Template

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, sitefinity

My CMS is developed in SiteFinity, now I have some component which is in React now I want to render my component from SiteFinity. do I need to write code in sitefinity template , if it is then what do I need to have in my sitefinity template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you'll need a custom widget, e.g. a Sitefinity Feather MVC widget and then you put your client code in the view. If you provide more details, we can respond with more details as well

Comment: I got Resolve this. What I did, I Goto Page's Content Blok and Edit and wrote Html there <div id="widgetName" data-react-component="ReactWidgetName">&nbsp;</div>, Rest I handle in Js file